# Reasons for compilation error

Tags: c

[image]

The HackerEarth facebook page uploads MCQs like these everyday! So, I suppose that I can share this image here. It seems to me like its a compilation error! Because of the fact that there is a statement the post-increments the `char` array `a` in the `for` loop!
But last 2 statements::

```
&lt;p<<k
}
```

Are they valid in any way? [< & > are converted to &gt; &lt; etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011392/are-converted-to-gt-lt-etc) This link says that `<` gets converted to `&lt;`! Or is it also a compiler error?

Was just curious because I couldn't trust myself that a compilation error as an extra closing bracket and a `&lt;p<<k;` statement could be there in a question!

Comment: Maybe it is possible .

Comment: There is no symbol `lt` so it seems that it should be a compilation error, unless that it means something in the compiler used (implementation defined). The same is also true for `p`.

Comment: @NabeelOmer did u see the link in the question??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last two lines are obviously not supposed to be there. This question is about the differences between arrays and pointers. You already found the answer: *a* is an array, not a pointer, and can therefore not be post-incremented.

Answer (score 2):

The

```
&lt;p<<k
}
```

is probably there by accident. It's gibberish. Leaving it out, you should get an error, because a is not a pointer. You can't increment an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
 &lt;p<<k
```

The above code might have occurred due to some improper closing of tags/fields in their HTML code.The following has no relation with the above c program.This program makes us understand that arrays can be accessed as pointers.